# Java1.8 Security Certifiate : TLS1.2 : Invalid supported_signature_algorithms

Tags: java, security, ssl-certificate, java-security

I am using jdk1.8 and working on Mutual Auth to connect to other system.
 I am using JVM Param to setup a client certificate/Server certificate. 
When sending a request, I am getting :

> javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Invalid
>   supported_signature_algorithms

NOTE: When I am using JDK1.7 it is working fine. I google this error but not able find an answer.

Comment: Could you please specify which version of jdk 1.7 you used for successful connection.